# TypeScript: typing the object key from an object that is inside another Object

Tags: generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

First of all, sorry for the bad title. I have a problem where I want to type the keys of a field inside a nested object.

Here is a snippet of my types:

```
type FormConfig<FormFieldIds extends string> = Record<FormFieldIds, OptionsConfig<FormFieldIds>>;

interface OptionsConfig<FormFieldOptions extends string> {
  type: 'checkbox';
  label: string;
  options: Record<FormFieldOptions, ValuePair>;
}

interface ValuePair {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}
```

My hook:

```
function useMyForm<FormFieldIds extends string>(
  config: FormConfig<FormFieldIds>
): {
  form: FormConfig<FormFieldIds>;
} {
  return { form: config };
}
```

My component:

```
export const MyPage = () => {
  const { form } = useMyForm({
    weekdays: {
      type: 'checkbox',
      label: 'Pick some days',
      options: { monday: { label: 'Monday is a great day!', value: 'monday' } },
    },
    months: {
      type: 'checkbox',
      label: 'Pick som months',
      options: { january: { label: 'January is cold', value: 'january' } },
    },
  });
};
```

This works perfectly when I only have one object, but when I add more objects TypeScript complains.

So the problem is that I cant type the keys of options object inside each object of the configuration. Does anybody know how I can do that?

I have made a sandbox with the code that gives more explanation. https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-leaf-ss2fi2?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use a `Record`:

```
interface ValuePair {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

interface OptionsConfig<FormFieldOptions extends string> {
  type: "checkbox";
  label: string;
  options: Record<FormFieldOptions, ValuePair>;
}

function useMyForm<
  Conf extends Record<string, OptionsConfig<string>>
>(
  config: Conf
): {
  form: Conf;
} {
  return { form: config };
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mMBJbW)